# Semantic highlight of unused variables in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am developing a Semantic Highlight extension for a custom language. I need to dim out unused variables.

According to [VSCode Semantic Highlight Classification](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#semantic-token-classification) I couldn't find any modifier that accounts for unused symbols.

If I analyse e.g. a Typescript program with VSCode default highlight, using Inspect Editor Token and Scopes command (see attached image), no additional attibute seems attached to the dimmed variable (in the image, the `UnusedClass` token has the same information of `UsedClass` token).

How can we create "unused" semantic tokens?

[VSCode Inspect Editor Token and Scopes screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yOOn.png)